# sum instances matching two strings in two different columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r, statistics, analysis

I am an R newbie, with significant experience in javascript. I would appreciate some help with this, as well as maybe any introductory resources that would help me calculate and analyze a dataframe that is mostly made up of strings.

Here is what the dataframe looks like

```
#  Gender  Nationality
1  Male    American
2  Male    American
3  Female  American
4  Male    French
5  Female  Spanish
```

I want to calculate the gender totals for each nationality. There are many nationalities so I would prefer an elegant solution that would allow me to do this all at once, with many nationalities and only two gender strings, male and female.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~gender,  ~nationality,
  "Male",    "American",
  "Male",    "American",
  "Female",  "American",
  "Male",    "French",
  "Female",  "Spanish"
)
```

A oneliner:

```
count(data, nationality, gender)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   nationality gender     n
#>   <chr>       <chr>  <int>
#> 1 American    Female     1
#> 2 American    Male       2
#> 3 French      Male       1
#> 4 Spanish     Female     1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `table` from `base R`

```
as.data.frame(table(data))
```